# How to compile java file which calls MeCab - Japanese part-of-speech & morphological analyzer?

Tags: java, unicode, classpath, text-analysis, mecab

I'm trying to use MeCab (http://mecab.sourceforge.net/#download) to do the word segmentation of Japanese sentences as well to tag every word by part of speech. I installed MeCab by following these instructions http://mecab.sourceforge.net/#install-unix. Since I don't want to write shell scripts to process 150,000 sentences (as my Mac OS X Terminal have problems showing Japanese characters), I'm using existing binding for Java: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mecab/files/mecab-java/0.98pre3/. At this point I'm trying to compile and run the given test.java file:

```
import org.chasen.mecab.MeCab;
import org.chasen.mecab.Tagger;
import org.chasen.mecab.Node;

public class test {
  static {
    try {
       System.loadLibrary("MeCab");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       System.err.println("Cannot load the example native code.\nMake sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains \'.\'\n" + e);
       System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
     System.out.println(MeCab.VERSION);
     Tagger tagger = new Tagger();
     String str = "太郎は二郎にこの本を渡した。";
     System.out.println(tagger.parse(str));
     Node node = tagger.parseToNode(str);
     for (;node != null; node = node.getNext()) {
    System.out.println(node.getSurface() + "\t" + node.getFeature());
     }
     System.out.println ("EOS\n");
  }
}
```

Here's the README:

```
1. Build UTF-8 dictionary

2. How to use?

  See test.java as sample program.

  % java -classpath MeCab.jar test -d ../dic
```

I compile: javac test.java. Then I run: java -classpath MeCab.jar test -d ../dic. The result is the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: //
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I don't really understand the hierarchy of this mecab-java-0.98pre3 directory, so don't see how to actually compile and run this test.java. Any ideas, guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you first run make? The first step is to actually build the mecab-java binding library.

```
$ tar -xvzf mecab-java-0.xx.tar.gz
$ cd mecab-java-0.xx
$ make
```

This will result in the following 2 files being output:

1. MeCab.jar
2. libMeCab.so

However, this assumes your platform is Linux, you have access to the make program, and that your Java includes are at /usr/local/jdk/include.

If this is not the case, then try reading the Makefile to see if you can build it on your own environment.

Comment: I'm actually running Mac OS X 10.6.7. Looks like I need to modify the following two lines in Makefile: 1) INCLUDE=/usr/local/jdk/include; 2) INC=`mecab-config --cflags` -I$(INCLUDE) -I$(INCLUDE)/linux. Do you know what values should be on the right hand side of each of these assignments? Thanks!

Comment: I've made the following changes in Makefile:
INCLUDE=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
INC=`mecab-config --cflags` -I$(INCLUDE) -I$(INCLUDE)/MacOS
However, I still have errors: MeCab_wrap.cxx:159:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
    MeCab_wrap.cxx:183: error: variable or field ‘SWIG_JavaThrowException’ declared void
    MeCab_wrap.cxx:183: error: ‘JNIEnv’ was not declared in this scope
    MeCab_wrap.cxx:183: error: ‘jenv’ was not declared in this scope
    MeCab_wrap.cxx:183: error: expected primary-expression before ‘code’

Comment: Never tried this on Mac OS, but this could help. http://hideki.posterous.com/using-mecab-from-java-on-mac-os-x

Comment: ok, after changing to INCLUDE=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers 'sudo make' works. Now what are the exact command to compile and run test.java? I'm doing: 1) javac test.java; 2) java -classpath MeCab.jar test -d /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic. This doesn't work, any advice?

Comment: When I do 'make test', it outputs, make: Nothing to be done for `test'. Why is that?

Comment: To run the test, all you need to do is run 'make test'. Try running 'make clean' to clean out the binaries; 'make' to re-compile; and then 'make test' to execute the test class once more.

Comment: I did what you said, still says 'nothing can be done'. So I run the following command: env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 test
Now output is 0.98pre3
å¤ ̾»ì,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
ª郎ã µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
¯ä ̾»ì,¸Çͭ̾»ì,Áȿ¥,*,*,*,*
º郎にこのæ µ­¹æ,°ìÈÌ,*,*,*,*,*
¬ã ̾»ì,¥µÊÑÀÜ³,*,*,*,*,* HOW TO SHOW JAPANESE CHARACTERS IN MAC OS X TERMINAL? I googled the topic, tried all kinds of settings for Terminal, nothing seems to work to show Japanese characters...

Comment: At this point, it looks like all you've got is an encoding issue, since the output appears to be indicative of a working mecab and mecab-java binding. Let's see if we can work out your terminal encoding issue.

Comment: What is the output of 'mecab -D'?

Answer (score 0):

For OS X I updated my makefile. I made several changes:

1. I set the `INCLUDE` to point to the OS X JAVA_HOME/include (using the `/usr/libexec/java_home` utility, which I *believe* is standard on OS X installs)
2. Set the second include path to include `$(INCLUDE)/darwin` instead of `/linux`
3. Change the CXX command to build a dylib instead of a linux .so library using the `-dynamiclib` compiler flag.
4. I also renamed the library, because the regular mecab lib and the jni wrapper are for some reason built with the same name, and since a default OS X install will be using a case insensitive file system, that could be very problematic. Instead of building `lib$(TARGET).so` I'm building `lib$(TARGET)Jni.dylib`
5. I also changed LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the `make test` to `DYLIB_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.` but I think that probably should work without being changed.

This is what my full makefile looks like.

```
TARGET=MeCab
JAVAC=javac
JAVA=java
JAR=jar
CXX=c++
INCLUDE=$(shell echo `/usr/libexec/java_home`/include)

PACKAGE=org/chasen/mecab

LIBS=`mecab-config --libs`
INC=`mecab-config --cflags` -I$(INCLUDE) -I$(INCLUDE)/darwin

all:
    $(CXX) -O3 -c -fpic $(TARGET)_wrap.cxx  $(INC)
    $(CXX) -dynamiclib  $(TARGET)_wrap.o -o lib$(TARGET)Jni.dylib $(LIBS)
    $(JAVAC) $(PACKAGE)/*.java
    $(JAVAC) test.java
    $(JAR) cfv $(TARGET).jar $(PACKAGE)/*.class

test:
    env DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=. $(JAVA) test

clean:
    rm -fr *.jar *.o *.so *.class $(PACKAGE)/*.class

cleanall:
    rm -fr $(TARGET).java *.cxx
```